# Netbeans JavaFx Cant select Main class

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

When I try to run my code in NetBeans I get a empty window saying "Browse JavaFX Application classes" but there are none to select. How can I solve this? Im trying to create a card game.
This is the start to the main method.

```
import cardutils.Deck;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {         
            Deck deck = new Deck();
            System.out.println(deck.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us a [mcve]?

Comment: How do you mean? None of my projects will run:(

Comment: They don't need to run. That's why you post them, so we can help you make them run.

Comment: Try a Clean & Build (shift-F6), Run File (shift-F11) or running from the command line,

Comment: When im trying to build it a empty window were it says "Available classes". The list is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make a JavaFX application, you need to create a class which extends the `Application` class of JavaFX and which also contains your main method. So something like this:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Deck extends Application {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Application.launch(args);
   }


   @Override
   public void start(Stage stage) {
      Group root = new Group(new Label("Hello JavaFX!"));
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1024, 786);
      stage.setScene(scene);
      stage.show();
   }
}
```

And then simply run the project and Netbeans will find this class because it contains a main method and will let you select it.

If, however, this project does not really need JavaFX (I just wondered because you're simply printing out something to the command line), you might have selected the wrong project type when creating your Netbeans project (JavaFX Project instead of normal Java Project). In this case create a new standard Java project and copy the code over from the old project.

**EDIT:** The list with "available classes" is empty because Netbeans can't find any classes that extend `javafx.application.Application` inside the JavaFX project you seem to have created.

Comment: Im having it as a javaFx because im using github with a partner. I've tried flushing the cache.

Comment: Whats the difference?

Comment: Simply put: If you want to or need to use JavaFX, use a class similiar to the one I posted above to let Netbeans find ("Available classes") and run your JavaFX application. If you don't want or need JavaFX, just create a normal project in Netbeans and it will recognize a class with a normal `main()` method as an executable class and will let you run it.

Comment: @TobiasHaraldsson Note that you don't actually need the `main()` method or the `Application.launch()` method. His code will work fine without them.

Comment: @LuminousNutria Yeah his code will compile but won't do anything without a main method :-)

Comment: I would really suggest updating your version of JavaFX.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. You may need to explicitly set source directory path. I fixed this problem by setting the source directory explicitly. File -> Project Properties -> Add Folder -> Browse your src directory. Build it and run again. I could run the application.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and they seem to be caused by residual files under in the project folder. I erased the folder and everything in it, and recreated a new project. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Netbeans 12.5) until I moved main() to the top of the class. After that I could move it back to the bottom again and it continues to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).