# No avilable classes when I run my program?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

[image: I am a new java coder. When I try to run my fx program, this square thing keeps popping up.]

I am a new java coder. I am unable to run the JavaFX program and this pop up of: Browse jAVAfx APPLICATION CLASSES keeps popping up with no available classes to choose from. Please Help!!

Comment: Does your class with `static main()` extends the javaFx Application class?

Comment: @itwasntme yes it does extend the application class

Comment: Try just running the project first (or the main method), then netbeans probably should find the class (found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382835/netbeans-javafx-cant-select-main-class ), Idk if this helps, I've used netbeans years ago :(

Answer (score 0):

Does your class include the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Hello Deckins!  Please explain in more detail why this answers the question.